# Get scala's case class parameters using java reflection API

Tags: java, scala

I need to get the member variables/parameters of scala case class in java. I tried using the java reflection API in the usual way but doesn't work with scala class.

```
List<Field> fields = getPrivateFields(myClass.class);
```

where `myClass` is a scala case class. How do I achieve this in java?

```
public static List<Field> getPrivateFields(Class<?> theClass){
List<Field> privateFields = new ArrayList<Field>();

Field[] fields = theClass.getDeclaredFields();

for(Field field:fields){
  if(Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())){
    privateFields.add(field);
  }
}
return privateFields;
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me. What is `getPrivateFields` doing and what exactly is the problem? Show a concrete example.

Comment: Added getPrivateFields method. Also, I referred that code from one of the stackoverflow answers.

Comment: And what is the problem? Do you get an empty list? Show your case class and the output of your program and state what you expected instead.